# Expected value of a game on the unit disc

Tags: probability

We play on the universe $S = \{ x^{2} + y^{2} \leq 1 \}$. We hit the disc with the point $(x,y)$ and we win $e^{(-x^{2} -y^{2})}$ money. Find the **expected value** knowing that we will never miss the board.

We know that $\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_ {-\infty}^{+\infty}y p_{x}(y)dy$
with $p_{x}(z)$ the **PDF**.

Knowing that we will never miss the board, we can already say that $\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_ {-1}^{1}y p_{x}(y)dy$.
Now I need to find $p_{x}(z) =\frac{d}{dz}F_{x}(z) = \frac{d}{dz}P(X\leq z)$.
In our example, we have $P(X\leq z)$ = $\frac{1}{\pi}$*Area*(*something* $\leq z$).
And **I'm stuck here.**

(I wrote a little program to approximate the expected value and I found $\approx0.5577$)

Comment: How do you write the program? Simulation? Then are you assuming the point is uniformly distributed on the disc?

Comment: Yes I used Monte-Carlo simulation using a uniform randomized vector between -1 and 1

Answer (score 0):

You have two random variables, $X$ and $Y$ (the coordinates of the target point), whose joint probability density function is $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=1/\pi$ for $x^2+y^2\leq 1$, and $=0$ otherwise. The expectation value of a function $T(X,Y)$ of $X,Y$ is by definition
$$
\mathbb{E}[T]=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}dx dy T(x,y)f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ .
$$
If $T(X,Y)$ represents the amount of money you win by hitting the target at coordinates $(X,Y)$, the expected value of $T$ is
$$
\mathbb{E}[T]=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{x^2+y^2\leq 1}dx dy e^{-(x^2+y^2)}=\frac{1}{\pi}\times 2\pi\int_0^1 dr\ r e^{-r^2}=\frac{\mathrm{e}-1}{\mathrm{e}}\approx 0.632...\ ,
$$
where one uses polar coordinates.